# Transparent space above 1st section in table view after rotate

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a split view controller, as the master view I have a UIViewController.  That UIViewController has a toolbar and a tableview inside it.

If I rotate the the split view to portrait and then back to landscape I see a space above the tableview that is transparent.  When I scroll the tableview up a little I see the table contents appear in that space.

Whats weird is that it only happens when I rotate the device and then rotate back again.  The table view is fine at first but something seems to get messed up after a couple of rotations.

Here is a screenshot of it after I rotate a few times:
[image]

Here is a screenshot before the rotation  (looks great):
[image]

I have tried to force it to re layout with setNeedsLayout, but no luck.

Any clue???

Comment: are you using autolayout ?

Comment: Did you tried setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in `viewDidLoad` of viewcontroller?

Comment: I am using autolayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in `viewDidLoad` of ViewController. This will be `YES` by default.

Comment: The important part here is to set that on the split view controller, not the master view controller inside the split view controller.